# django 1.4 on production not seeing any model and app

Tags: django, django-admin

On production when I create a user throught admin site or shell (is_staff=True) I can't add any my models. I see only: Can add/change/delete log, group, permission, user. My models aren't there. Why?
But on developer server all everything is Ok.

I use django 1.4
My config developer and production is defferent on settings_local.py. But there only Database,

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, 
DEBUG = True, 
DEBUG_GRID = False, 
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend', 
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

That's all.
```

Comment: Could you give us the code snippet where you try to create a user?

Comment: in shell: In [3]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User

In [4]: user = User.objects.create_user('user02', 'user02@user.com', 'user')

In [5]: user.is_staff=True

In [6]: user.save()

Comment: I try give permissions for new user by superuser in admin site.

Comment: Have you new user created after you do create_user() from a command line? I mean the problematic production server.

Comment: Yes, user was created. I can login in admin site by this user. But I can't edit anythings.

Comment: Please, check also is_staff flag for the created user retrieving him from a database (user = User.objects.get( username = ... ), user.is_staff). If is_staff set then the settings are really different.

Comment: Because when I login by superuser and try give a permissions for editing my models, i can't see any my models in "Specific permissions for this user".

Comment: Yes, I know it. "Specific permissions for this user" isn't change when is_staff = True or False on production. But on developer it changes...And i see my models!

Comment: The 'staff' permission only guarantees that user can enter admin. Please read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310983/django-admin-specific-user-admin-content

Comment: Really? I did it in other projects. It was two users: one - superuser, other user, who didn't create users and groups, but could edit content on site.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register you models to django-admin to do operations on them in the admin site.

Example:

```
models.py
class ModelA():
  ...


admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
admin.site.register(ModelA)

urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
```

Update: With Staff login you won't be able to access the models. Staff status only allows you to login into the admin site. To let them perform CRUD operation you need to give them permissions. 
Now, if you can not see the permission it could be because of you don't have them in the first place check out your database to be sure.

Comment: I registered my model in admin.py. I see it when I login by superuser. But other user don't see it. And I don't give them this priveleges, because I can't see it in "Specific permissions for this user".

Comment: But this problem only production! On dev everything is Ok

Comment: @Olga: Updated the answer take a look

Comment: Well, How I can check out my database?

Comment: You would have to look for the table auth_permission in your database or login as superuser to see what permission do you have

Comment: I did:  select * from auth_permission; and in this tables hasn't permission for my table. But it only production, on dev it has. Why?
`
`

Comment: I am not sure it can be because of several reasons. So, fixing the Permission table should solve the problem you are facing

Comment: I added one model in table auth_permission, I see in  "Specific permissions for this user". But when I login in other user with this permission i see: "you haven't enough permission for edit".

Comment: Well for each model django has different set of permission to perform the CRUD operations. Probably your logged in user is missing the edit permission

Comment: No, I created new user 'admin' (not a superuser) thought admin site and added permission: 'can add city'. But when I login by 'admin' i see: You don't have a permission for edit.