# Managing two kind of users in one application

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am not an expert in Django and learning it by doing. I am making an application and it has two kind of users-

```
 User who offers services
 User who uses services
```

So my query is how to manage these two types of users? One possible approach i am thinking of is make two separate profile models for both these users and have different login pages for these users. And still I want to have upper layer of Django admin which can manage both these users. So my problem is-Is there any particular way to implement this kind of scenario or i can go with my approach? These users will have different privileges like offer-er of service can add his service while simple user can only use that service by logging in himself. So i want to have a secure separation between these users.

Comment: Django doc has a section dedicated to this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using django's built in Groups and custom Permissions. Also another interesting tidbit I would consider is implementing two versions of the django admin.

[How to have 2 different admin sites in a Django project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206856/how-to-have-2-different-admin-sites-in-a-django-project)

Comment: Not exactly what i was looking for but it was helpful. Thanks